# Getting image from REST API and uploading it to Firebase Cloud Storage using Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, rest, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

## What I need to accomplish

I need to fetch images from rest API (base64) and write individual images into Firebase Cloud Storage. After image is successfully written, write log into Firebase Realtime Database.

## What's the problem

Well, I initialized Firebase app (Cloud Functions) with AdminSDK, because I need some admin features (for instance bypassing Realtime Database rules). According to Firebase documentation, if I use AdminSDK, then for manipulating Cloud Storage I must use "@google-cloud/storage".

So I looked up [documentation](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html#upload) for "@google-cloud/storage" and found out that for uploading files I have to call method ".upload" and specify path to file as argument.

**The problem is I don't have path to that file because I have it as base64 string**. I can't generate path for it, because nodeJS doesn't have method URL.createObjectURL and polyfiling that method is impossible. Also writing that image to filesystem is not solution, because Cloud Functions is read-only environment.

## Things I tried

- Polyfiling URL.createObjectURL, but it didn't work
- Use nodeJS module FS to write images from REST API to filesystem, upload them to Cloud Storage and then remove them.

### Is there any solution to this problem, or some recommended way to do this kind of functionality?

Comment: Hello, can you share your code?

Comment: [Cloud Functions documentation#File System](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#file_system) mentions that the environment provides a writable `/tmp` directory, why not just write the file there...?

Comment: @esqew, oh, thank you, I forgot about that option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

My second solution (writing temporary file using fs) was almost right, but I forgot to specify file destination to `/tmp`. In Firebase Cloud Functions is everything but `/tmp` read-only storage.